# CentOS 6 donwgrade RPMForge packages

Tags: centos6, yum, repository

I have a CentOS 6.6 server, and I tried some packages from rpmforge and rpmforge and extras. I did a yum update with those repos enabled and got a lot of stuff updated. Now I want to go backwards and replace all .rf an .rfx packages and have them replaced with the ones from standar repos. Is that posible???

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whay I ended up doing and worked for me:

```
yum list installed | grep @rpmforge
rpm --erase --nodeps <list obtained with first command>
```

Then disabled rpmforge repos from the config files

```
yum install <list obtained with first command>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `yum history list` to see recent yum transactions.

Use `yum history info <ID>` to view the details of a transaction.

Use `yum history undo last` to revert the most recent transaction, or `yum history undo <ID>` to revert a specific transaction.

Comment: mmm thanks, but that goes back the whole transaction... and how that deals with dpenedencies??? I just want to revert packages that got updated with rpmforge rpms...